storeResouce is too slow with remote interface
eXistDB 6.2.0
Saving to a locally running database via the remote interface is several orders of magnitude slower compared to using an embedded database. I can't figure out where the problem lies, or how to store the data more efficiently.
I need to store about 100,000 records. When saving via the remote interface, the speed is around 100 records per second. However, when using the embedded database, the speed is about 9,000 records per second.
What am I doing wrong, or how can I improve this?
Below is a code example.
remote uri: xmldb:exist://localhost:8080/exist/xmlrpc
embeded uri: xmldb:exist://
In both cases the db is running on the same machine. db configuration file is attached.
    final Random random = new Random();
    final HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
        double latitude = MIN_LAT + (MAX_LAT - MIN_LAT) * random.nextDouble();
        double longitude = MIN_LON + (MAX_LON - MIN_LON) * random.nextDouble();

        String randomId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String randomName = generateRandomString(random, 30);
        String randomValue = generateRandomString(random, 10);

        String resourceId = prefix + "/" + randomId;
        String xml = String.format(
                """
                        <entity>
                            <name>%s</name>
                            <value>%s</value>
                            <pos>%.8f %.8f</pos>
                        </entity>""",
                randomName, randomValue, latitude, longitude
        );
        data.put(resourceId, xml);
    }
    xmlDbService.saveEntity(data);
}

public void saveEntity(@NonNull HashMap<String, String> resources) throws Exception {
    var sortedResources = new TreeMap<>(resources);

    Collection col = null;
    String currentCollectionUri = null;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    try {
        for (var entry : sortedResources.entrySet()) {
            String resourceId = entry.getKey();
            String xmlData = entry.getValue();

            var param = splitResourceId(resourceId);
            String collectionUri = param[0];
            String resourceName = param[1];

            if (col == null || !collectionUri.equals(currentCollectionUri)) {
                if (col != null) {
                    col.close();
                }
                col = getOrCreateCollection(collectionUri);
                col.setProperty("indent", "no");
                currentCollectionUri = collectionUri;
            }

            i++;
            if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                log.info("Inserted: {}, rate {} / sec", i, c * 1000L / executionTime);
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                c = 0;
            }
            XMLResource res = (XMLResource) col.createResource(resourceName, XMLResource.RESOURCE_TYPE);
            res.setContent(xmlData);
            col.storeResource(res);
            c++;
            log.trace("Resource saved: {} in collection: {}", resourceName, currentCollectionUri);
        }
    } finally {
        if (col != null) {
            col.close();
        }
    }
} ```

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.exist-db</groupId>
    <artifactId>exist-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.xmldb-org</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmldb-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
Thank you for your help and/or advice.

V.


@vlada It looks like you are using the XML:RPC interface. As your URI indicates you are using it against the local machine, we can probably ignore any network performance issues. I suspect the performance cost comes from serialization/deserialization of the documents across XML:RPC and possibly the implementation of the XML:RPC interface itself. You might want to consider using one of the other interfaces to see if performance is improved, for example the WebDAV or REST interfaces?

With the REST API is speed quite similar. Maybe 10% faster. But still 50 times slower than with embedded.
public void saveEntityREST(String resourceId, String xmlData) throws Exception {
    String[] param = splitResourceId(resourceId);
    String collectionPath = BASE_URL + param[0] + "/";
    String resourceName = param[1];

    URL url = new URL(collectionPath + resourceName);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD));
    connection.getOutputStream().write(xmlData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK && responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to save resource: " + responseCode);
    }
}

